# LazyLaoding CSS background (not HTML <img> tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

I've managed to figure out how to lazyload images on my website where the images are called into the HTML via `<img>` tags. [I used this package on GitHub to accomplish this.](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#include-the-script) However I'm having trouble acomplishing the same thing with CSS `background:`'s.

**-Some information on the issue:**

I created an image menu bar last night that changes image size/position based on the browsers screen *(Link provided)*. All the images in this image menu bar are called in via `background:` within the CSS (not through an `<img>` tag).

**-Now for my question:**

How am i able to lazyload the `background:` images within the css of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Shololom/wbgn210y/) project I've started. On my website I would just change `<img src="">` to `<img data-src=""` (within the HTML) after following the instructions from the Github link above, and **images will load as they become visible on the screen**.

**-Reason for doing this:**

This is purely to speed up the website and to avoid loading all images at once. *Any other tips to ensure this does not take a toll on loading time, or any other possible ways around this issue would be appreciated.*

**-Note:** I've used `background:` and not `background-image:` for this project.

*If you missed the link to my project:* https://jsfiddle.net/Shololom/wbgn210y/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Github project](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#lazy-background-images) you provided :

### Lazy background images

When to use: your images are set as CSS background images instead of real img, but you still want to lazily load them.

#### HTML

```
<div class="lazy" data-src="../img/44721746JJ_15_a.jpg"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
    elements_selector: ".lazy"
});
```

That's it. Whenever the element selected by elements_selector is not an img or an iframe, LazyLoad puts the image found in the data-src attribute in the background-image of the element.

## Edit: Complete example:

```js
// Get products
var product1 = document.getElementById('product1');
var product2 = document.getElementById('product2');
var product3 = document.getElementById('product3');
var product4 = document.getElementById('product4');
var product5 = document.getElementById('product5');

// Create Lazy loader
var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
    elements_selector: ".lazy"
});

// Load images in a responsive way
function loadImgs() {
 console.log('Loading images ...');
   var src1;
    var src2;
    var src3;
    var src4;
    var src5;    
 if(window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width:700px)").matches) {
      /* The viewport is lesser than 700 pixels wide */
   src1 = product1.getAttribute('data-src-small');
    src2 = product2.getAttribute('data-src-small');
    src3 = product3.getAttribute('data-src-small');
    src4 = product4.getAttribute('data-src-small');
    src5 = product5.getAttribute('data-src-small');      
   
  } else {
   src1 = product1.getAttribute('data-src-large');
    src2 = product2.getAttribute('data-src-large');
    src3 = product3.getAttribute('data-src-large');
    src4 = product4.getAttribute('data-src-large');
    src5 = product5.getAttribute('data-src-large');   
  } 

  // Set the data-src for lazy loader
  product1.setAttribute('data-src', src1);
  product2.setAttribute('data-src', src2);
  product3.setAttribute('data-src', src3);
  product4.setAttribute('data-src', src4);
  product5.setAttribute('data-src', src5); 
    
  // Tell lazy loader that the data should be re-processed
  product1.removeAttribute('data-was-processed');
  product2.removeAttribute('data-was-processed');
  product3.removeAttribute('data-was-processed');
  product4.removeAttribute('data-was-processed');
  product5.removeAttribute('data-was-processed');   
  
  // Tell lazy loader to update
  myLazyLoad.update();
}

// Load images first time
loadImgs();

// Reload images when window is resized
var lastWindowSize = window.innerWidth;
window.onresize = function(event) {
 var currentWindowSize = window.innerWidth; 
 if((lastWindowSize <= 700 && currentWindowSize > 700) || (lastWindowSize > 700 && currentWindowSize <= 700)) {
   loadImgs();
  }
 
  lastWindowSize = currentWindowSize;
};
```

```css
.top-header-settings {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  margin: 0 0 45px;
  padding: 45px 0 0;
  color: #524949;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.top-menu-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  ;
  background-color: #343434;
}

.top-menu-inner {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 260px;
  /*/background-color:#343434;/*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-menu-innerr {
  max-width: 1161px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.top-menu-button {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: .6;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.top-menu-button:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
}

.top-menu-text {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  /*/background-color:red;/*/
  margin: 150px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #343434;
  -khtml-opacity: .50;
  -moz-opacity: .50;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=50)”;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity: .60;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.coming-soon-top {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  background: #c78f8f;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  .top-menu-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #343434;
  }
  .top-menu-inner {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 340px;
    /*/ background-color:#343434;/*/
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .top-menu-innerr {
    max-width: 80%;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*/background:red;/*/
  }
  .top-menu-button {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: white;
  }
  .top-menu-button:hover {
    opacity: .6
  }
  #product2 {
    /*background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080");*/
    /*/background:#c77f7f;/*/
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  #product1 {
    /*background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080");*/
    /*/background:#c77f7f;/*/
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  #product3 {
    /*background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080");*/
    /*/background:#c77f7f;/*/
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  #product4 {
    /*background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080");*/
    /*/background:#c77f7f;/*/
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  #product5 {
    /*background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080");*/
    /*/background:#c77f7f;/*/
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 1080px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .top-menu-text {
    /*/width:125px;/*/
    /*/height:30px;/*/
    width: 30vw;
    height: 10vw;
    /*/background-color:red;/*/
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5.9vw;
    line-height: 9vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-lazyload/8.7.1/lazyload.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-menu-warp">
  <div class="top-menu-inner">
    <div class="top-menu-innerr">


      <a href="#">
        <div id="product1" class="top-menu-button lazy" 
          data-src-small="http://via.placeholder.com/220x220"
          data-src-large="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080">

          <div class="coming-soon-top">
            Most Popular
          </div>

          <div class="top-menu-text">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div id="product2" class="top-menu-button lazy" 
          data-src-small="http://via.placeholder.com/220x220"
          data-src-large="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080">
          <div class="top-menu-text">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div id="product3" class="top-menu-button lazy" 
          data-src-small="http://via.placeholder.com/220x220"
          data-src-large="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080">
          <div class="top-menu-text">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div id="product4" class="top-menu-button lazy" 
          data-src-small="http://via.placeholder.com/220x220"
          data-src-large="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080">
          <div class="top-menu-text">
            Text
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>

       <a href="#">
        <div id="product5" class="top-menu-button lazy" 
            data-src-small="http://via.placeholder.com/220x220"
            data-src-large="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080">

          <div class="coming-soon-top">
            Coming soon
          </div>

          <div class="top-menu-text">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

[A jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramrami/wbgn210y/23/)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, 
thanks for the response. What confuses me is that within my CSS a smaller version of the image is called if the screen is large, and a larger responsive version of the image is called when the screen is smaller. I'm confused as to how the above method would work. Would it be too much to ask if you can edit the example project I created for this question?
-regards

Comment: @cactusboat I updated my answer with a complete example. You should remove all background from the css. And handle responsive behavior with javascript. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Mpdhamed I have changed some of the js. Mainly all the 700px identifiers to 1200. 

I have also swapped around the following:

var src1 = product2.getAttribute('data-src-large');
...
and
var src1 = product1.getAttribute('data-src-small');
... (all of them).

It works all fine, however sometimes when you resize the window, the images that were meant to become smaller, are cropped out as they are in their large state within the small image frame.

Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/Shololom/wbgn210y/27/

Is something interfering with the JS from running properly?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to acheive. You want to show small images when the screen is large, and big images when the screen is small ?

Comment: Or do you mean that on of the small image, go into new line ?

Comment: if so remove the margin from `.top-menu-button`

Comment: Alternatively use IntersectionObserver:
https://www.sitelint.com/blog/lazy-loading-css-background-images-for-better-website-loading-performance/